# Replace missing small caps by uppercase

Tags: fonts, glossaries, small-caps

I am using `glossaries` with the `sc` option to set acronyms in small caps.  This works fine in the main text, but the font I am using for sectioning (and, importantly, `description` labels) does not have small caps, so that problems like this occur:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}
\newacronym{sc}{smallcaps}{little big letters}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\section{\Glsname{sc} in a section title}
\Gls{sc}

\section{this is better: \GLSname{sc}}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to replace the small caps in the sans-serif font with “big caps” (or maybe faked small caps).  Is there a way to do this?

*Note:* I have a semi-satisfactory solution based on `\GLSname` for sectioning and `\let\glsnamefont\uppercase` for the glossary.  I still wonder if it would be possible to make a “smart” replacement based on the font.

Answer (score 5):

You can emulate the inexistent small caps sans serif font with `\small\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}
\newacronym{sc}{smallcaps}{little big letters}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand\glsnamefont[1]{\small\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{\Glsname{sc} in a section title}
\Gls{sc}

\section{this is better: \GLSname{sc}}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is an improvement visually.  I guess what I am really looking for is a way to redefine `\textsc` to mean `\small\uppercase` just for the sans font.

Comment: @xebtl No, you don't. `;-)` My suggestion is to use an existing font, rather than doing a patch that's worse than the hole (as we say where I live). The choice made by KomaScript of using sans serif for description lists is quite strange, in my opinion, and has little typographical justification.

Comment: Well, you may be right about that font choice.  I never questioned if the description label should be the same font (family) as the sectioning.  Even KOMA-Script's custom `labeling` environment does not do that!